# Python: How to place columns with identical names from different dataframes adjacent to each other?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to know if there's a way in Python to place columns from different dataframes with the same names (or related names) adjacent to each other.

I know there's the option to use `JOIN`, but I would like to make a function from the scratch that can achieve the same.

**Example:**

Let's assume 2 dataframes `df1` and `df2`

`df1` is

```
id A  B
50 1  5
60 2  6
70 3  7
80 4  8
```

`df2` is

```
id  A_1  B_1
50   a    b
60   c    d
70   e    f
80   g    h
```

Expected Output: A new dataframe, say `df3`, looking like this

```
   id A  A_1  B  B_1
   50 1   a   5   b
   60 2   c   6   d
   70 3   e   7   f
   80 4   g   8   h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `sorted()` with column names like:

```
m=pd.concat([df1.set_index('id'),df2.set_index('id')],axis=1)
m[(sorted(m.columns))].reset_index()

   id  A A_1  B B_1
0  50  1   a  5   b
1  60  2   c  6   d
2  70  3   e  7   f
3  80  4   g  8   h
```

Answer (score 1):

First you `join` the 2 dataframes -

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, how='inner')
```

And then you can sort the index -

```
df3 = df3.sort_index(axis=1)
```

Comment: Hey, @Mortz. Thank you for your response. I am aware that a join could be used, but I was wondering if a function can be made from scratch to achieve the same. Thanks

Comment: From scratch? Can you clarify? Do you mean not using the pandas library at all? Maybe, you can take a look at the pandas codebase to get an idea on how such functionality is implemented

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about the same. Thanks

Comment: Hey @Mortz, when I try your method, I am getting the following error `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`